# Mobius inversion

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

Your goal is to implement [Möbius inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), a linear operation on a sequence of numbers that is [used in combinatorics and number theory](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/BenderGoldman.pdf). Fewest bytes wins.

**What is Möbius inversion?**

Given a (finite) integer sequence `f_1, f_2, ..., f_N`, we can compute its divisor-partial-sum `g`, whose `n`th element `g_n` is the sum of all terms `f_d` whose index `d` is a divisor of `n`.

```
g_n = sum_(d with d|n) [f_d]

g_1 = f_1
g_2 = f_1 + f_2
g_3 = f_1 + f_3
g_4 = f_1 + f_2 + f_ 4
g_5 = f_1 + f_5
g_6 = f_1 + f_2 + f_3 + f_6
...
```

The sequence `g` has the same length as `f`.

[Möbius inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) is the process of inverting this operation -- recovering `f` from `g`. This inverse is unique and produces an integer sequence. A explicit but complicated way to compute it is the [Möbius inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), which expresses `f_n` as a weighted sum over divisors `d` of `n`:

```
f_n = sum_(d with d|n) [μ(d) * g_(n/d)]
```

and `μ` is the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function):

```
μ(n) = 1 if n is a square-free positive integer with an even number of prime factors.
μ(n) = −1 if n is a square-free positive integer with an odd number of prime factors.
μ(n) = 0 if n has a squared prime factor.
```

**Program requirements**

Write a [function or program](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/20260) to perform Möbius inversion. Fewest bytes wins. Built-in methods to perform Möbius inversion, do sequence convolution, compute the Möbius function (or related thing like checking squarefreeness), or solve systems of equations are not allowed.

**Input**

A sequence of integers of length at least 1. Can be any format that represents an ordered sequence: array, list, stack, token-separated string, etc. Unordered maps from the index to the element like dictionaries and functions are not OK. You're not given the length of the input sequence separately.

**Output**

Return or print the output sequence in any format, with same restrictions as input. It should be the same length as the input sequence.

**Test cases**

```
Input: [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 2, 6]
Output:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Input: [0, -3, 6, 5, 1, 7, 5, 0, 4, 0]
Output: [0, -3, 6, 8, 1, 4, 5, -5, -2, 2]

Input: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output: [1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1]
```

Comment: I think solving a linear system with inbuilt functions should be prohibited completely.

Comment: @Optimizer Using built-ins to solve linear systems is already banned; what more do you mean? Prohibiting inverting matrices? In any case, I'm not going to make changes at this point. I agree that matrix-based solutions are hard to beat, which I hadn't foreseen, so please consider it a separate league if it makes you feel better.

Comment: See the J answer. Aolving `Ax=B` for a matrix is equivalent to solving system of equations only.

Answer (score 5):

## J - 13 char

Anonymous function Mobius-inverting a sequence.

```
(%.0=#\|~/#\)
```

Here's what's going on:

- `#\` gets indices from 1 to the length of the input list, inclusive.
- `|~/` makes a table of indices modulo themselves.
- `0=` checks for equality to zero, 1 for true, 0 for false. On the table of moduli, this checks divisibility, returning a matrix like

  ```
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
  ```
- Finally, `%.` takes the input sequence and this matrix, and solves it as a linear system: `x` equal to `b %. A` is the solution to `Ax=b` if it exists. Our `b` is the input sequence and `A` is this divisibility matrix above.

In use: (Note that J spells its negative sign `_`)

```
   (%.0=#\|~/#\) 1 2 2 3 2 4 2 4 3 4 2 6 2 4 4 5 2 6 2 6
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   (%.0=#\|~/#\) 0 _3 6 5 1 7 5 0 4 0
0 _3 6 8 1 4 5 _5 _2 2
   (%.0=#\|~/#\) 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 _1 _1 0 _1 1 _1 0 0 1 _1 0 _1
```

Comment: Sorry, but you're not allowed to use methods that solve linear systems. You can perform matrix operations though (or is that what your code is already doing?).

Comment: @xnor Yes, it's only matrix inversion. It states in the [the documentation](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d131.htm) that `b%.A` is shorthand for `(%.A) mp b` where `mp` is the matrix product, and `%.A` is matrix inversion on `A`.

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab/Octave <strike>(56)(53)</strike>(51)

51 chars:

```
i=input('');x=1:numel(i);disp(i/~bsxfun(@mod,x,x'))
```

53 chars:

```
i=input('');x=meshgrid(1:numel(i));disp(i/~mod(x,x'))
```

I basically set up system of linear equations in matrix form where the matrix looks like this (depending on the length, here the length is 6:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Then I just solve the corresponding system of equations.

The command `meshgrid(x)` is primarly inteded for producing matrices like

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

and

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

which can then be used as e.g. x and y coordinates for plotting 2d functions. I just use one of them for ceating a matrix with where the k-th column has is 0 every k-th element via elementwise remainder division (modulo). `~` as the logical `not` which replaces nonzero values with zeros and vice versa, which then results in the matrix above.

Comment: How is this solving the system of equations? If it's just using the built-in CAS solver, that's not allowed, but if you're inverting the matrix, that's fine. My apologies that I edited in that restriction after posting the question, so you might not have seen it.

Comment: It is using a built in numerical solver (you can assume it is the gauss algorithm), Matlab/Octave are numerical computing languages that do not allow algebraic manipulations - so is this still ok?

Comment: I think I need to understand what `(i/~mod(x,x')` is doing. Could you please explain?

Comment: ´i´ is the input vector (as a row vector). `/` is divides the vector by the matrix and `~mod(x,x')` represents the matrix. (I'll write more in my answer, just noticed the comment is too short.)

Comment: OK, that's totally fine. The code expresses an explicit solution to the matrix equation; it's not being implicitly solved.

Comment: Ok thanks, I really liked this crisp short challenge just before going to bed=)

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 99 chars

```
def I(g):
 f,e=[],enumerate
 for n,v in e(g):f+=[v-sum(x for i,x in e(f)if(n+1)%(i+1)<1)]
 return f
```

Computes `f` from `g` incrementally, so we can use the `f`s we've already calculated to compute larger `f`s.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 67 bytes

This can be golfed further, but given that so many languages can solve linear equations with 1 character, I don't see a point in answering with any non-maths oriented language.

```
l~:F,,{):N,:){N\%!},{__mF{W=1>},,{;0}{_mF,\1=m2%W1?}?N@/(F=*}%:+}%p
```

This is the exact implementation of the Möbius inversion formula.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Takes input from STDIN in the following format:

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

and gives output line

```
[1 -1 -1 0 -1 1 -1 0 0 1 -1 0 -1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 61

```
h g=[v-sum[h g!!n|n<-[0..i-2],rem i(n+1)<1]|(i,v)<-zip[1..]g]
```

this solves the equations one at a time using the already known values of `f`, using laziness.

this is inefficient in space and time complexity because it recomputes the result several times ( it's like the difference between `fix f=f(fix f)` and `fix f=r where r=f r`). a simple fix:

```
h g=r where [v-sum[r!!n|n<-[0..i-2],rem i(n+1)<1]|(i,v)<-zip[1..]g]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 84 chars

```python
g=input()
i=1
for _ in g:g[i-1]-=sum(g[j-1]*(i%j<1)for j in range(1,i));i+=1
print g
```

Iterates through the entries, making each one what it needs to be for the sum to work out. Modifies the input list directly rather than making a new list.